# How to create a table in a Ruby on Rails application via console on Openshift?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, openshift

I have a gem installed called 'rhc', but how can I create a table for a Ruby on Rails application via rhc command?

Comment: This can be closed as Too Broad: _Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question._

Comment: I am attempting again to close this as Needs More Focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the documentation always helps, there seems to be areas you can look at:

https://developers.openshift.com/en/ruby-getting-started.html

https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-adding-a-database.html

These seem to have all the info you need.

If you have started your app, probably best to provide us with some code to show us what you have done so we can see how best to help you.

If you are using the OpenShift Rails (3/4) quickstart, it is automatically setup to run the rake db:migrate command when you do a git push to deploy your code for your application (https://github.com/openshift/rails4-example/blob/master/.openshift/action_hooks/deploy).

If you are trying to do it manually, you need to SSH into your application, cd into the ~/app-root/repo directory, and run `RAILD_ENV={your_env} bundle exec rake db:migrate`, but this possible won't work because the rails gem is probably not installed.  The best way is the git push method (once you have written your migrations)

Comment: sometimes its a lot easier to ask someone who knows, rather than eating all the documentation to find a few answers...just exhausted to read))...thanks

Comment: Have you found the answer? What have you done so far?